# How to replace the InnerText of a Comment

Tags: c#, openxml

I've tried the following:

```
comment.InnerText=comment.InnerText.Replace(comment.InnerText,new_text);
```

Which doesn't work because we can only read the InnerText property. How do I effectively change the InnerText value so I can save the modifications to `WordProcessing.CommentsPart.Comments` and `MainDocumentPart.Document` ?

EDIT: `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Comment` is comment's class.

EDIT 2: The method:

```
public void updateCommentInnerTextNewWorkItem(List<Tuple<Int32, String, String>> list){

//DOCX.CDOC.Comments -> WordProcessingCommentsPart.Comments
//DOCX._CIT -> Dictionary<int,string>

        foreach (var comm in DOCX.CDOC.Comments)
        {
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                foreach (var item_cit in DOCX._CIT)
                {
                   if (((Comment)comm).InnerText.Contains("<tag>") && item.Item3.Contains(item_cit.Value))
                   {
                       comm.InnerXml = comm.InnerXml.Replace(comm.InnerText, item.Item1 + "");
                     //comm.InnerText.Replace(comm.InnerText,item.Item1+"");
                       //DOCX.CDOC.Comments.Save();
                       //DOCX.DOC.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
                   }

                   if (((Comment)comm).InnerText.Contains("<tag class") && item.Item3.Contains(item_cit.Value))
                   {
                       //comm.InnerText.Replace(comm.InnerText, item.Item1 + "");
                       comm.InnerXml = comm.InnerXml.Replace(comm.InnerText, item.Item1 + "");
                       //DOCX.CDOC.Comments.Save();
                       //DOCX.DOC.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
                   }
                }   
            }                    

        }

        DOCX.CDOC.Comments.Save();
        DOCX.DOC.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();

    }
```

Comment: What is the comment a class of? It isn't really known from the snippet shown.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing in inner Text in open xml element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869861/replacing-in-inner-text-in-open-xml-element)

Comment: @PhilippeParé I want to replace the InnerText, not InnerXml.

@ZacharyDow I'm using `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Comment`.

Comment: Using the mainDocumentPart.Document.Save(); from @PhilippeParé 's possible duplicate doesn't work?

Comment: @ZacharyDow The problem is not when saving the document parts (it works fine), it's the process of replacing the innertext content. What I provided doesn't work, like it is explained in the duplicate's second answer. I want to know how I can replace the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not such easy(but still not complex). Comment has structure as well as document's body - it could contain Paragraphs, Runs etc. InnerText will just return to you text values of all runs of all paragraphs in this comment, so now you understand why you can not just set this value.

So first you have to remove all comment's paragraphs:

```
comment.RemoveAllChildren<Paragraph>();
```

Next step is to add new paragraph with run that contains text you need:

```
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
Run run = new Run();
Text text = new Text();
text.Text = "My comment";
run.Append(text);
paragraph.Append(run);
comment.Append(paragraph);
```

After all do not forget to save changes:

```
doc.MainDocumentPart.WordprocessingCommentsPart.Comments.Save();
```

Answer (score 2):

It's read-only because it returns the XML content with all XML tags removed.  So setting it would strip it of all XML tags.

If the text you want to replace does not span tags you could just replace the text in the XML:

```
comment.InnerXml=comment.InnerXml.Replace(comment.InnerText,new_text);
```

Comment: @D Stanley It's not working that way either. The InnerText stays the same.

Comment: @dcgc Can you give more of the code, maybe the error is somewhere else... a reference type thing

Comment: @PhilippeParé Code is in OP.

Comment: @dcgc OP = Original Poster.  You mean "question"

Comment: Have you run it in the debugger?  `InnerText`will not contain XML tags unless they are encoded within tags themselves, so your `if` statements are probably not getting hit.

Comment: @DStanley Yes, I've used the debugger and the `if` statements do get hit.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh....This is a little complex.And I have ever had the same problem.

You will need the XmlElement Class.And for example, there is a variable named xmlDoc which has been instantiated from XmlDocument.
And then you should use the method SelectSingleNode to get the reference of which XmlNode you want to edit.Here you need to transform the XmlNode into XmlElement by using this(Suppose the XmlNode is named 'node'):

```
XmlElement XmlEle = (XmlElement)node;
```

Also in easy way, you can use this:

```
XmlElement XmlEle = (XmlElement)xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("dict/integer");
```

And now you can use the variable XmlEle to replace the InnerText because it's just a reference.

Like this:

```
XmlEle.InnerText = TopNumber.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

just use not innterxml , user text

```
 foreach (Paragraph paragraph in document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph>())
            {
                bool ss = paragraph.InnerXml.Contains("commentRangeStart");
                bool ee = paragraph.InnerXml.Contains("commentRangeEnd");
                if (ss && ee)
                {
                    foreach (Run run in paragraph.Elements<Run>())
                    {
                        foreach (Text text in run.Elements<Text>())
                        {
                                text.Text = "your word " ;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```