# How to add hyperlink to Comment's InnerText

Tags: c#, hyperlink, openxml

Similar to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075170/how-to-replace-the-innertext-of-a-comment), I'm trying to add an hyperlink to the current comment's InnerText. The hyperlink is added successfully, but when I try to open the .docx file, the comments.xml file is malformed. The error is at the hyperlink tag, inside the comment's paragraph tag, created in the XML file. Is something wrong with the code bellow?

```
comm.RemoveAllChildren<Paragraph>();
HyperlinkRelationship relation =
                       doc.MainDocumentPart.AddHyperlinkRelationship
                       (new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), true);
                       String relationshipId = relation.Id;

Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
Hyperlink hl = new Hyperlink(
                            new Run(new RunProperties(
                            new RunStyle()
                            {
                                Val = "Hyperlink"
                            }),
                            new Text(currentCommText)
                            ))
                            {
                                History = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OnOffValue(true),
                                Id = relationshipId
                            };
paragraph.Append(hl);
comm.Append(paragraph);
cdoc.Comments.Save();
doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
_________________________________________________________________________________________

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:comments ...>
<w:comment w:initials="d." w:author="User" w:date="2015-08-19T16:45:00Z" w:id="8">
    <w:p>
        <w:hyperlink w:history="true" r:id="R8bd7676b70ad4dad">
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:rStyle w:val="Hyperlink" />
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t>Text</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:hyperlink>
    </w:p>
</w:comment>
...
</w:comments>
```

Comment: your code don't seems wrong. What is the error given by word ? have you edit document.xml to add cr/lf to have the exact line

Comment: @MaximePorté I've tried unziping the .docx file and comparing "before" and "after" state XML files, particularly the comments.xml file. They both seem similar (except of course, the added hyperlink (like I've shown in the XML block above)). Here is a screen of what happens when I try to open the .docx file, after adding the hyperlink:
http://i.imgur.com/CBp2qjk.png

The error is in the hyperlink tag so something must be wrong.

Comment: Also tried the official Open XML Schema Strict .xsd's with the .xml of the xml block in the question, in Visual Studio, and everything seems fine... I still don't understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your problem, it's the rId of the Hyperlink who's not good (I recreate a docx document, and the only time I succeed to recreate your problem is by changing the rId to a bad one).

My guess is (I didn't try it, but I think it would solve the problem) the creation of an hyperlink for comments musn't be

```
doc.MainDocumentPart.AddHyperlinkRelationship
```

but

```
doc.MainDocumentPart.WordprocessingCommentsPart.AddHyperlinkRelationship
```

**edit: Documentation**

A quick read at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc850832.aspx explain how to insert a comment in word document.

If you take a look in your ".zip" folder, comments are in a separated file (comments.xml). So when you create xml code for your comment and it refers `WordprocessingCommentsPart` it seems logical to add Hyperlink rid in this part too

Comment: Still have the same exact problem on the hyperlink tag line (maybe it's the rId again).

Comment: @dcgc is your xml code for comments is in comments.xml or document.xml ?

Comment: The code I provided in the question is located in the comments.xml file.

Comment: I forgot to close the document, that was part of the problem (that's why I  also didn't get to work following your answer, which is also correct). Also, creating a relationship is not necessary.